# How can I make SQLite reuse a prepared statement, like a query plan cache?

Tags: sqlite, database-performance

My app uses SQLite to store data, and I have one query that runs often. When I profile the app, preparing the statement for the query (`sqlite_prepare_v2`) takes the huge majority of the time. Actually fetching data (`sqlite3_step`) takes very little time.

I am using bind args for the parameters of the query, and I know that in larger-scale database systems like SQL Server or MySQL, one advantage of using bind args is that the database engine can reuse query plans. Based on my performance testing of SQLite with and without the bind args (`select id from foo where bar = 1` vs `select id from foo where bar = ?`), it does not appear to have a built-in query plan cache. Is it possible to build one myself, by caching the `sqlite3_stmt` pointer and re-binding new parameters to it later, or something like that?

Edit: as a further detail, if I reuse the `sqlite3_stmt` object, I'd ideally like to make a copy of it, because I'm in a multithreaded environment and I'd like multiple threads to be able to use a prepared statement at once. Otherwise I have to do something funky involving each cached prepared statement having its own mutex. So how do I copy a `sqlite3_stmt` object?

Comment: Correct, [you're expected](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html) to reuse the output of the `sqlite_prepare_*` function using `sqlite3_bind_*` to bind new values to it.

Comment: @AnonCoward see the edit above for a detail of reuse - how do I copy a prepared statement?

Comment: You don't copy it.  Multiple connections [shouldn't reuse the same database connection unless you're in serialized mode](https://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html), so you either just reuse the same prepared statement if you're in serialized mode, or rerun prepare on the SQL statement for the other modes.

Answer (score 0):

Call `sqlite3_reset(prepared_statement)` to reset the prepared statement to its original state. You can then rebind the placeholders with the various bind functions before calling `sqlite3_step`. If you plan to keep the prepared statement around for a long time, you can use prepare_v3 to give it a hint flag that you are using the prepared statement like that.

As for how that affects performance, that probably depends on a number of different factors, and you will most likely need to profile to figure out what works best for your use case.